# How PyQt5 cursor above QListWidget item pops WhatsThis documentation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

How to give a definition for each item in QListWidget, so that the cursor changes to WhatsThis Cursor and pops an doc of explication
 when the cursor is over it?

Something like this **but for an item of QListWidget**

[image]

I tried simply:

```
for i, def in zip(range(self.listWidget.count()), some_doc):
    self.listWidget.item(i).setWhatsThis(def)
```

But the doc didn't show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be the correct way to set the `WhatsThis`. However, you state that you want this to appear on hovering, which is instead the tooltip property.

solution:

```
for i, def in zip(range(self.listWidget.count()), some_doc):
    self.listWidget.item(i).setToolTip(def)
```

If you want this behavior only in WhatsThis mode, you will have to subclass the QListWidgetItem and set the tooltip to only return when `QtWidgets.QWhatsThis.inWhatsThisMode()` is true.

If you really are just having problems with the `WhatsThis` property working on click, we will need to see more of your code and possibly a screenshot of your window. Because like I said, the loop at the beginning should work at just setting the normal property.

Comment: Great, I only need the first case. To be completed the rest, other people might need it, but that's the solution I want